# specify LDAP Query

Tags: active-directory, ldap

When I ping 140West-dc it returns:

```
Pinging 140West-dc.bvncap.local
```

And my LDAP Query is as follows:

```
LDAP://dc=bvncap,dc=local
```

Is there anyway to pass `"140West-dc.bvncap.local"` to LDAP query instead of just `"bvncap.local"`

Note: `140West` is my office location.

EDIT:

I pass the common name to the query like this:

```
LDAP://cn=140West-dc,dc=bvncap,dc=local
```

But get an error:

```
Run-time error : There is no such object on the server
```

Here is the command text:

```
SELECT AdsPath FROM 'LDAP://cn=140West-dc,dc=bvncap,dc=local' WHERE objectCategory='user' And sAMAccountName = 'hjose'
```

Get this error when i execute:

```
set rs = cmd.Execute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/130543/how-can-i-figure-out-my-ldap-connection-string) first.

You could try this connection string:

`LDAP://140West-dc.bvncap.local/dc=bvncap,dc=local`

Answer (score 1):

LDAP connection strings need the following syntax:

```
LDAP://[<server name>/]<baseDN>
```

The server name is optional, but if needed, can be an IP address or any resolvable DNS entry (i.e., 140west-dc or 140west-dc.bvncap.local).  If not specified, it'll connect to a DC that's associated with the IP range in AD Sites & Services.

The baseDN is where in the directory you connect.  You can connect to the root of your domain (dc=bvncap,dc=local), or a subdomain of your parent domain (dc=subdomain,dc=bvncap,dc=local), or an OU somewhere underneath that (ou=Level2,ou=Level1,dc=bvncap,dc=local).  This affects where your search begins.

There's some good info here: [LDAP ADsPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746384(v=vs.85).aspx)

Also, your WHERE clause should have "objectClass=user" or "objectCategory=person".  However, that attribute isn't needed, as sAMAccountName is unique within the directory, so it'll only return one object either way.