# LDAP client on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server

Tags: ubuntu, ldap

I am setting up an LDAP client on Ubuntu 14.04 server and can't seem to be able to logon. I see an error in the `auth.log` that says `unknown user`.

I installed packages:

```
ldap-auth-client
ldap-auth-config
libldap-2.4-2
libnss-ldap
libpam-ldap
```

I modified `/etc/ldap.conf` with my URI and base. I also modified `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to include ldap in passwd, group, and shadow. I can successfully ping the URI. I have setup gerrit on another system to use LDAP using the same setting as in `ldap.conf`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you able to search for your account using `ldapsearch`?

e.g.`ldapsearch -x -h <servername> uid=<some_user_id>`

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't post any of your configuration, it is hard to guess, but going from the error message you provided, it seems you are trying to login as an unknown user.
Check, if your're using the right LDAP-String.

So maybe this can help you: [How can I figure out my LDAP connection string?](https://serverfault.com/questions/130543/how-can-i-figure-out-my-ldap-connection-string)

Comment: The install asked me the name of the ldap server and the distinguished name of the search base. I see in /etc/ldap.conf

Comment: In my ldap.conf, I have _italic_ **bold** `base dc=xxxx,dc=com`, where xxx is my company name. then uri [link](ldap://eng-auth.xxxx.com). The rest of the file is mostly comments except _italic_ **bold** pam_password md5